# Alter superclass' variable from subclass on Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take this example,

```
class A():
    dictionary={'item1':'value1','item2':'value2'}

class B(A):
```

I want to be able to add a third item to the already existing dictionary of the superclass from class B. Not completely override it, just add a third value.

How can this be done?

Comment: `A.dictionary["foo"] = "bar"`?

Comment: Presumably you want `B` to have *their own copy* of the dictionary, so the same dictionary as `A` but with something added. `A` should itself not have the extra key, right?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that will add it for `A`, too

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes but I have no idea what override means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create a copy of the mutable dictionary into `B`:

```
class B(A):
    dictionary = A.dictionary.copy()
    dictionary['key'] = 'value'
```

You could do that in one step with the `dict()` callable:

```
class B(A):
    dictionary = dict(A.dictionary, key='value')
```

Either way `B.dictionary` now has 3 key-value pairs, while `A` has just the two:

```
>>> class A():
...     dictionary={'item1':'value1','item2':'value2'}
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     dictionary = dict(A.dictionary, key='value')
... 
>>> A.dictionary
{'item2': 'value2', 'item1': 'value1'}
>>> B.dictionary
{'item2': 'value2', 'item1': 'value1', 'key': 'value'}
```